# Entire Bootstrap Navigation Bar a png?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, navigation

I have been looking through the bootstrap documentation and all the examples show how to add just a simple logo onto the basic navigation bar.

I designed my .png file that I want to use as the navigation bar. Is this possible to do?

I then would like to add navigation links etc ontop of the png as I would add them to the regular nav bar.

```
<style type="text/css">
.bgimg {
    background-image: url('bannerReal.png');
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark static-top bgimg>
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
              <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: You can check examples here:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/
Download code and check its HTML/CSS.
Can try this one: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/product/

Comment: @sssurii all those examples show adding a log image on the navbar. I want to replace the entire navbar with an image. Adding some code I am trying to my post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you pasted should work... provided that you added your style block after loading the bootstrap.css file... you can check the snippet below and verify also.

```css
.bgimg {
  background: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/seekadventure.net.storage/bannerReal.png);
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark static-top bgimg">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
              <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**UPDATE**:
CSS updated in light of questioner's shared image

Comment: It scrunches my image into the rectangle. The bottom of my image is not perfectly straight and I want that to show

Comment: Give a complete public URL of your image so that I can see what you mean

Comment: https://s3.amazonaws.com/seekadventure.net.storage/bannerReal.png

Comment: @searayman you can check now and let me know if it works for you...

Comment: Nope, I want the entire bar to be my image

Comment: try changing to `background-size: contain;` for the class `.bgimg` - else can you share a screenshot of what you expect?